# C : file binary - Stack around the variable 'tempEmployee' was corrupted

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I've tried to handle this error but no success. I have the next functions which are supposed to create a binary file, fill it until user enter employee code that is not in range 0-100 and i get this error

the function create_binary_file get the error when she done.

> Stack around the variable 'tempEmployee' was corrupted

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct employee{
      int  code;
      char  name[15];
      float  salary;
} Employee;

void create_blank_salary_board (char * filename);
void create_binary_file (char * filename);
void print_binary_file (char * filename);


void main(){
    char filename[] = "EmployeeSalary.dat";
    create_binary_file(filename);
    print_binary_file(filename);
}

void create_blank_salary_board (char * filename){
    int i;
    Employee tempEmployee = { 0, "", 0.0 };                                             // create Employee with default information
    FILE *cfPtr;                                                                        // "filename" file pointer
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( filename, "wb" ) ) == NULL ) 
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
    else{
        for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ )                                                    // output 100 blank records to file
            fwrite( &tempEmployee, sizeof(Employee), 1, cfPtr );
        fclose( cfPtr );
    }
}

void create_binary_file (char * filename){
    FILE *cfPtr;
    Employee tempEmployee =  { 0, "", 0.0 };                                                // create Employee with default information
    create_blank_salary_board(filename);
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( filename, "rb+" ) ) == NULL ) 
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
    else{
        printf( "Enter account number ( 1 to 100 )\n? " );
        scanf( "%d", &tempEmployee.code );
        while ( tempEmployee.code > 0 && tempEmployee.code <= 100 ) {                       // user enters information, which is copied into file
            printf( "Enter name, salary\n? " );                                             // user enters name and salary
            scanf( "%s%lf", tempEmployee.name, &tempEmployee.salary );
            fseek( cfPtr, ( tempEmployee.code - 1 ) * sizeof( Employee ), SEEK_SET );       // seek position in file to user-specified record
            fwrite( &tempEmployee, sizeof( Employee ), 1, cfPtr );                          // write user-specified information in file
            printf( "Enter account number\n? " );                                           // enable user to input another account number
            scanf( "%d", &tempEmployee.code );
        }// end while
    fclose( cfPtr ); // fclose closes the file
    } // end else
}

void print_binary_file (char * filename){
    Employee tempEmployee = { 0, "", 0.0 };
    FILE *cfPtr;
    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( filename, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) 
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
    else { 
        printf( "%-6s%-16s%10s\n", "Code", "Name", "Balance" );
        fread( &tempEmployee, sizeof( Employee ), 1, cfPtr );       // read all records from file (until eof)
        while ( !feof( cfPtr ) ) { 
            if ( tempEmployee.code != 0 ) /* display record */
                printf( "%-6d%-16s%10.2f\n", tempEmployee.code, tempEmployee.name, tempEmployee.salary );
            fread( &tempEmployee, sizeof( Employee ), 1, cfPtr );
        } // end while
      fclose( cfPtr ); // fclose closes the file
   } // end else
}
```

Comment: `scanf( "%s%lf",` --> `scanf( "%s%f",` : Use `%f` for `float`.

Comment: Thank you. i can't believe that was the error.

Comment: Anyway I suggest not to write a struct with a single fwrite, since you don't know how many bytes it occupies. Better write a function which writes/reads each element individually and use a int32_t for the code.